# C++ polynomial class, print member function not working well with the power

Tags: c++

I'm making a polynomial class with some basic operations on two polynomials. 
My other member functions work well except the print function.
here is my print member function:

```
void Polynomial::print() const
{
    string plus;//plus is the plus sign in front of every element except the first element
    plus="+";
    int k=0;//k is the power of the each element in the polynomial
    if(coefficient[0]!=0)
        cout<<coefficient[0];

    for(int i=1;i<coefficient.size();i++)
    {

        if(coefficient[i]==-1234)
            break;


        if(coefficient[i]==0)
        {
            k++;
        }
        else if(coefficient[i]==1)
        {
            if(coefficient[i]>=1)
                cout<<plus;
            cout<<"x";
            k++;
        }
        else if(coefficient[i]==-1)
        {
            if(coefficient[i]>=1)
                cout<<plus;
            cout<<"-x";
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(coefficient[i]>=1)
                cout<<plus;
            cout<<coefficient[i]<<"x";
            if(coefficient[i]!=-1234)
            {
                k++;
            }
            else
                break;
            if(k>1)
            {
                cout<<"^"<<k;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;

    return;
}
```

NOW if the user inputs: 1 2 3 1
the polynomial prints as : 1+2x+3x^2+x
the 4th term in the polynomial does not have a correspond k (power) of 4. 
I've been checkin my code for hours...still don't know where goes wrong.
Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Review the `else if(coefficient[i]==1)` block.

Comment: you have strange conditions: `if(coefficient[i]==1) { if(coefficient[i]>=1)` (always true) and `if(coefficient[i]==-1) { if (coefficient[i]>=1)` (always false)...

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should be like this. You are not printing the power when the coefficient is 1 or -1:

```
for(int i=1;i<coefficient.size();i++)
{

    if(coefficient[i]==-1234)
        break;


    if(coefficient[i]==0)
    {
        k++;
    }
    else if(coefficient[i]==1)
    {
        if(coefficient[i]>=1)
            cout<<plus;
        cout<<"x";
        k++;
        if(k>1)
        {
            cout<<"^"<<k;
        }

    }
    else if(coefficient[i]==-1)
    {
        if(coefficient[i]>=1)
            cout<<plus;
        cout<<"-x";
        k++;
        if(k>1)
        {
            cout<<"^"<<k;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if(coefficient[i]>=1)
            cout<<plus;
        cout<<coefficient[i]<<"x";
        if(coefficient[i]!=-1234)
        {
           k++;
        }
        else
            break;
        if(k>1)
        {
            cout<<"^"<<k;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're entering for the last `1` this block:

```
    else if (coefficient[i] == 1)
    {
        if (coefficient[i] >= 1)
            cout << plus;
        cout << "x";
        k++;
    }
```

spoiling the `x^power` part.

A possible solution could be:

```
void print()
{
    string plus;
    plus = "+";
    int k = 0;
    if (coefficient[0] != 0)
        cout << coefficient[0];

    for (int i = 1; i<coefficient.size(); i++)
    {

        if (coefficient[i] == -1234)
            break;


        if (coefficient[i] == 0)
        {
            k++;
        }
        else if (coefficient[i] == 1 && i == 1 /* This prevents entering here afterwards */)
        {
            if (coefficient[i] >= 1)
                cout << plus;
            cout << "x";
            k++;
        }
        else if (coefficient[i] == -1 && i == 1 /* This prevents entering here afterwards */)
        {
            if (coefficient[i] >= 1)
                cout << plus;
            cout << "-x";
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (coefficient[i] >= 1)
                cout << plus;
            cout << coefficient[i] << "x";
            if (coefficient[i] != -1234)
            {
                k++;
            }
            else
                break;
            if (k>1)
            {
                cout << "^" << k;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

it really boils down to how you're comfortable at printing and formatting the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
void print_polynom(const std::vector<int>& coeffs)
{
    const char* plus = "";
    const char* space = "";

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != coeffs.size(); ++i) {
        if (coeffs[i] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (coeffs[i] > 0) {
            std::cout << space << plus << space;
        } else {
            std::cout << space << "-" << space;
        }
        plus = "+";
        space = " ";
        if (i == 0 || std::abs(coeffs[i]) != 1) { // to avoid to print 1x^k
            std::cout << std::abs(coeffs[i]);
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << "x";
        if (i == 1) { // not print x^1
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << "^" << i;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/KKd4Dh)